# Хочу скачать файл в aiogram и сохранить в формате text

Tags: python, aiogram

Отправляет пользователь файл

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.DOCUMENT)
async def oo(doc: types.document.Document):
    file_id = doc['document']['file_id']
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    result = await bot.download_file(file_path, '/Users/nnnnn/Documents/python__programs/еее/tt.txt')
```

в итоге получается вот это

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica-BoldOblique;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\i\b\fs24 \cf0 PYTHON\
AIOGRAM\
\uc0\u1055 \u1040 \u1049 \u1058 \u1054 \u1053  \
\uc0\u1060 \u1049 \u1054 \u1043 \u1056 \u1040 \u1052 }
```

А хотелось бы чтобы файл сохранялся в таком же виде в котором отправляют.
Ну или что надо сделать чтобы вернуть файл в прежнее состояние

Comment: это RTF формат - открывается WordPad и стандартным RichText в Windows. from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text rtf = "some rtf encoded string" text = rtf_to_text(rtf) print(text)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь